# lazy watcher does not execute

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-options-api

I am new vuejs.as shown in the below posted code, the `isBtnDigitizePolygonClicked` is a reactive variable.i am trying to execute some lines of code as a side effect to the change of the value of `isBtnDigitizePolygonClicked`. for that reason, i used `watch` as shown below
in the code.

the problem i am encountring now, is when the code is executed, and despite the methos`onDigitizePolygon` is called, the log messages in the watched variable `isBtnDigitizePolygonClicked` never shows up as if the watcher did not execute

please let me know why that is happening and how to solve it.

**code**:

```
let isBtnDigitizePolygonClicked = ref(true);
...
... 
watch: {
    isBtnDigitizePolygonClicked(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log(debugTag, 'newVal:', newVal);
        console.log(debugTag, 'oldVal:', oldVal);
        if (digitizePolygonInteractions) {
            if (newVal == true) {
                digitizePolygonInteractions.remove();
            } else {
                digitizePolygonInteractions.add();
            }
        } else {
            throw new Error('WTF.digitizePolygonInteractions is:');
        }
    },
    immediate: false,
},
computed: {
    compPropsIsBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled() {
        if (isBtnDigitizePolygonClicked.value == true) {
            return values.CONST_STRING_DIGITIZE;
        } else {
            return values.CONST_STRING_STOP_DIGITIZE;
        }
    },
},
methods: {
    onDigitizePolygon() {
        console.info(debugTag, 'onDigitizePolygon()');
        isBtnDigitizePolygonClicked.value = !isBtnDigitizePolygonClicked.value;
    },
}
```

**template**:

```
<button @click="onDigitizePolygon()">{{ compPropsIsBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled }}</button>
```

Comment: That's weird. it is a mixture of options api and composition api. you have to choose one first, and then we can go on to help you. please rewrite the code part.

Comment: @AliBahrami i thought i am using only options-api..would you please tell me which part is written in composition - api

Comment: that ref is the composition api: let isBtnDigitizePolygonClicked = ref(true);

Comment: @AliBahrami but when i removed the declaration of `isBtnDigitizePolygonClicked =ref(true)` i received the following error: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: isBtnDigitizePolygonClicked is not defined

Comment: See johan answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think my mistake was, that i did not add the `isBtnDigitizePolygonClicked` to the return of the `data()'

**code**:

```
data() {
    return {
        isBtnDigitizePolygonClicked,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the options-api, you can directly write:

```
data() {
    return {
        isBtnDigitizePolygonClicked: true,
    }
}
```

What comes in `data() {..}` is automatically reactive.
Therefore, there is no need for

```
let isBtnDigitizePolygonClicked = ref(true);
```